# Graph showing 1K instead of GB's about Disk's in Ganglia/RRDTool

Tags: linux, monitoring, rrdtool, rrd, ganglia

I'm using `Ganglia` and `RRDTool` to show charts in a web page.
Everything is fine, but for some machines the graphs about `DISK` are with some kind of bug.
Here is how they look in some machines (both machine are in the same `cluster`):

This one is correct, about the disk space:

[image: correct]

But this one is showing 1.4Kb of disk space. Which is incorrect. How can I fix this ?
Any idea ? I already uninstall it and install it many times, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got in touch with `Ganglia Developers` e-Mail list, they told me that the value is correct, which means `1.4K GB`, which are `1400GB` or `1.4T`. I was all a misunderstanding. I just think it should be a documentation more clear about what are the metrics.

Comment: does ganglia give you the ability to change labels and unit exponent?

Comment: @austin, after a lot of research I found out that it gives, but you have to change it in the source code to do that. Be aware that if you do that you could affect other metric that use the data that you alter. I just kept the same thing to avoid this kind of issue in the future.

Comment: interesting. seems like a really logical thing to include. sounds like a good enhancement request.